# Redirect to error page when an error occurs while loading a partial view in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know if i can possibly redirect to error page when an error occurs while loading a partial view on pop up. I'm displaying some datas on my partial view from API.

my js code

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

            $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
                $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                    $('#myModal').modal({
                        keyboard: true
                    }, 'show');
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Right now it displays the error page inside the pop up. It should be redirected to another page.

**EDIT**

Implementation of Error Catch

Webconfig

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
   <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <error statusCode="403" path="/Error/Index/403" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
   <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/Index/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
   <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/Index/500" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Error Controller

```
  public ActionResult Index(int id = 500)
        {
            var model = new ErrorPageViewModel();
            model.ErrorCode = id;
            switch (id)
            {
                case 403:
                case 404:
                    model.ErrorHeader = "Page not Found!";
                    break;
                default:
                    model.ErrorHeader = "Oops, something went wrong!";
                    break;

            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function callback can take additional parameters which would allow you to know whether the request succeeded or not and act accordingly:

```
$('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function (response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == 'error') {
        // oops some error occurred => redirect the user to your error page
        window.location.href = '/error500';
    } else {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it it's not working. Error page still displayed on modal pop up. I edited my question. Thanks

Comment: According to the code example I have shown either the modal will be displayed or redirected to the error page. But not both. So I suppose the problem is in some other part of your code.

Comment: I removed httpErrors tag inside my webconfig and your code works.

Comment: I think Http Handlers blocks the ajax request.